# Best method for creating Python Spacy NLP objects from a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, spacy

I would want to create Spacy nlp objects out of 250k string objects stored in a Pandas data frame column. Is there a way of optimizing the following "apply" approach, i.e., is there some way of vectorizing the call of the spacy nlp object?

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3], "text": ["this is a text", "another easy one", "oh you come on"]})

df["nlp"] = df.apply(lambda x: nlp(x.text), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my tests on a corpus of 29,071 strings, a faster method than `apply` is with `nlp.pipe`

```
import pandas as pd
import spacy
from time import time
from nltk.corpus import webtext

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")  
texts = webtext.raw().split('\n')
df = pd.DataFrame({"text":texts})

#apply method
start = time()
df["nlp"] = df.apply(lambda x: nlp(x.text), axis=1)
end = time()
print(end - start)

# batch method
start = time()
df["nlp"] = [doc for doc in nlp.pipe(df["text"].tolist())]
end = time()
print(end - start)
#print(Counter([tok.dep_ for tok in doc if tok.pos_=='VERB']))
```

Output:

```
apply method: 209.74427151679993
batch method: 51.40181493759155
```